# Heroku error: heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE --confirm gentle-sunset-3760

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I run most commands via the heroku gem, I get the following error:

```
/Users/me/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:30:in `start': undefined method `error_with_failure' for Heroku::Helpers:Module (NoMethodError)
from /usr/bin/heroku:28
```

The following work:

`heroku logs`

`heroku restart`

The following don't work and return the above error:

`heroku run console`

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

`heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE --confirm spiteful-beaver-2000`

The logs reveal a problem with my db (not migrated to current). It was when I tried to migrate the db to fix that simple problem (actually, I first tried restarting the db with the last command above) that I first encountered the error. I've upgraded the gem to no avail.

How can I fix this? I'd rather not start that app over (ie transfer it to another app on heroku).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the toolbelt fixed it.

One way to uninstall:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/heroku
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/heroku
```